# making TCP web Server with python

Tags: python, tcp, server, webserver

I have created a multi threaded python web server and it is working fine for my client server.However i want it to take results work for web server as well. Please help me understand how we do that

the server

```
import socket
import threading
import os
import sys

#to convert bytes into string 
def bytestoString(stringToRead):
        stringToRead = bytes.decode(stringToRead)
        type(stringToRead)
        return(stringToRead)

#to conver string into bytes
def stringToBytes(bytesToSend1):
        bytesToSend1= str.encode(bytesToSend1)
        type (bytes)
        return(bytesToSend1)
#to retreive a file
def retrFile(name,sock):
    fileName=sock.recv(1024)
    fileName_string = bytestoString(fileName)
    print(fileName_string)
    stringLength=len(fileName)
    fileName_string = bytestoString(fileName[4:(stringLength-8)])


    if os.path.isfile(fileName_string):
        fileSize=str(os.path.getsize(fileName_string))
        fileSize_Bytes = stringToBytes(fileSize)
        exists_Bytes=stringToBytes('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')
        sock.send(exists_Bytes)
        ContentLength_Bytes=stringToBytes('Content-Length:')
        sock.send(ContentLength_Bytes+fileSize_Bytes)
        userResponse=sock.recv(1024)
        userResponse=bytestoString(userResponse)
        if userResponse[:2]=='Y':
            print ('Ready to send the file................')
            with open(fileName_string,'rb') as fileRead:
                data= fileRead.read(1024)
                sock.send(data)
                while data!="":

                    data=fileRead.read(1024)
                    sock.send(data)
            fileRead.close()
            print('xyz')

        elif userResponse[:2]=='N':
            print('User Terminated file download, Thanks for connecting')

    else :
        httpResponse=stringToBytes('HTTP/1.1 404 not Found')
        sock.send(httpResponse)  

    sock.close()


def Main(serverPort):
    #creating a server socket type TCP
    serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    localHost=socket.gethostname()
    #binding the server to the client
    serverSocket.bind((localHost,serverPort))

    serverSocket.listen(5)

    print ('***Server is ready to recieve***')

    while True:

        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        print ('got connection from:<', addr,'>')
        t=threading.Thread(target=retrFile,args=('retrThread',connectionSocket))
        t.start()
    connectionSocket.send('thank you for connecting')
    connectionSocket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #getting server hostname and port number from the user
    serverPort=int(sys.argv[1])
    Main(serverPort)
```

The Client

```
import sys
import socket

#to convert bytes into string 
def bytestoString(stringToRead):
        stringToRead = bytes.decode(stringToRead)
        type(stringToRead)
        return(stringToRead)

#to conver string into bytes
def stringToBytes(bytesToSend):
        bytesToSend= str.encode(bytesToSend)
        type (bytes)
        return(bytesToSend)

#def header():

def Main(serverName,serverPort,fileName_bytes,fileName):
    print('***Initialising the socket***')
    serverAddress=(serverName,serverPort)

    #create the TCP/IP socket using user inout for server and port

    clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect(serverAddress)
    httpFileRequest=('GET/'+fileName+' HTTP/1.0')
    httpFileRequest=stringToBytes(httpFileRequest) 
    #Reading the Hostname,socket family, socket type, protocol for the server 

    connectionDetails= socket.getaddrinfo(serverName,serverPort)
    #printing the values to the screen
    print (connectionDetails)
    #print('Family:',families)
    #print('type:',types)
    #print('protocol:',protocols)



    #Sending the request to recieve the file from the server

    if fileName_bytes!="q":
        clientSocket.send(httpFileRequest)
        serverResponse=clientSocket.recv(1024)
        serverResponse_string = bytestoString(serverResponse)
        print(serverResponse_string)
        fileLength=clientSocket.recv(1024)
        fileLength_string = bytestoString(fileLength)
        print(fileLength_string)
        #checking the server response and downloading the file
        if serverResponse_string[13:15]=='OK':
            fileSize= float(int(fileLength_string[15:17]))
            print(('Size of file you wish to download is:'),fileSize)
            clientChoice=input('Please Enter Your Choice (Y/N)?:')
            if clientChoice=='Y':
                clientChoice=stringToBytes(clientChoice)
                clientSocket.send(clientChoice)

                #recieveing the file from the server

                file = open('new_'+fileName,'wb')
                print ('file opened.............')
                data=clientSocket.recv(1024)
                totalRecv=float(len(data))
                file.write(data)
                while totalRecv<fileSize:
                    data=clientSocket.recv(1024)
                    totalRecv+=len(data)
                    file.write(data)
                    percentComplte=int(int((totalRecv)/int(fileSize)*100))
                    print (('we have completed'),percentComplte,('%'))
                file.close()
                print ('Download complete')
            elif clientChoice=='N':
                clientChoice=stringToBytes(clientChoice)
                clientSocket.send(clientChoice) 
                print ('File download terminated')
            else :
                print ('Please enter the correct choice')
        else: 
            print (serverResponse_string)

    clientSocket.close()
    #Getting Hostname,socket family, socket type, protocol for the server 
def get_constants(prefix):
    """Create a dictionary mapping socket module constants to their names."""
    return dict( (getattr(socket, n), n)
                 for n in dir(socket)
                 if n.startswith(prefix)
                 )

#calling main function 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #getting server hostname and port number from the user
    serverName=sys.argv[1]
    serverPort=int(sys.argv[2])
    fileName= str(sys.argv[3])
    fileName_bytes = str.encode(fileName)
    type(bytes)
    Main(serverName,serverPort,fileName_bytes,fileName)
```

Comment: what are those `type`-calls for? You are using `recv` wrong.

Comment: You need to implement the real HTTP protocol and not something which only remotly looks like this. This means properly parse the client response to extract the information and also send proper HTTP responses. I recommend to actually read the standards, maybe starting with HTTP/1.0 because it is simpler. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) for more information and links to the standards. Since a good answer would first need to explain how HTTP really works I consider this question as too broad.